# How can I set a variable to a text input and then make it appear on screen

Tags: javascript, input, var

I am making a text based game for school and I am stuck with trying to set a variable as an text input. What I would like to happen is the player type start into the input and it do what is inside of the if statement. However from there I would like the player to enter a username and then it set the variable of "name" to what they input but with out it saving the name as "start".

```
//js

var name = "";
var beginBeenTo = false;
    if (beginBeenTo == false) {
        if (input == "START") {

            beginBeenTo = true;

            page = page + 1;
            healthPoints = 25;

            soundEveningBreeze.play();
            $("#welcome_message").show().insertBefore("#placeholder").delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            $("<br><p class='text'>You there, what is your name?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").delay(7000).fadeIn(3000);

            if (input != "" || namingBeenTo == false) {
                name = input;
            }
        }
    }

document.getElementById("print_name").innerHTML = name;
```

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: `$("input_form")` should be `$("#input_form")`, if you mean an input with id `input_form`.

Comment: @Henderikus : which is the input field you are using to get the username?. can you provide some jsfiddle?.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, watch for some event (`keyup` in my case), check if the input value is `START`, if so ask for a username.

```js
var started = false;
var username = '';
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  var tmpValue = $(this).val();
  if(started){
    username = tmpValue
  }
  if(tmpValue === 'START') {
    started = true;
    $(this).val('')
    $(this).attr('placeholder','Username')
  }
  
  $('#username').text(username)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="username"></span>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type START to play">
```

Comment: this is not quite what i meant, what you had before was more like it. i need a variable to update when they enter the input

Comment: the username currently updates once `started == true` - I'm not sure how this is different.

Answer (score -1):

it could be done with use of function like this :

```
var name = "";    
$("form").submit(function() {
var input = $("#command_input").val().toUpperCase();
if (input == "START") {
name = $("#input_form").val();
}
}
document.getElementById("print_name").innerHTML = name;
```

**you were missing one of #(hashtag)**

**And this code would work**

**Thanks & Cheers**

Comment: You do not need `document.getElementById` either as you could simply use `$`